# why isn't my array being rendered on my page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to render listed property information from an array of objects. I used this method in another part of my project with success, but in this instance, I am not getting anything at all.

here is the code I have

```jsx
import { database } from "../../components/firebase";
import { ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const dbRef = ref(database);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const array = [];

  const getData = () => {
    get(child(dbRef, "users/"))
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        setUsers(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const getProperties = () => {
    Object.values(users).forEach((user) => {
      Object.values(user?.properties).forEach((property) => {
        array.push(property);
        console.log(property);
      });
    });
    console.log(array);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getProperties();
  }, [dbRef]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Properties </div>
      <div>
        {array.map((property) => (
          <div key={property.property_id}>
            <h1>{property?.property_name}</h1>
            <p>{property?.description}</p>
            <p>{property?.rooms}</p>
            <p>{property?.phone}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <p>oi</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Nothing happens, it only prints "properties" and "oi"

Comment: how do i force it to update ? if i add users to the useEffect listener, the page ends up in a loop

Comment: @lams I would make getData an async function and then await it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData` is asynchronous. When you execute `getProperties`, your `users` state will still be its initial, empty array value.

You don't appear to be using `users` for anything else but assuming you want to keep it, the easiest way to drive some piece of state (`array`) from another (`users`) is to use a [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

```jsx
// this is all better defined outside your component
const usersRef = ref(database, "users");
const getUsers = async () => (await get(usersRef)).val();

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({}); // initialise with the correct type

  // Compute all `properties` based on `users`
  const allProperties = useMemo(
    () =>
      Object.values(users).flatMap(({ properties }) =>
        Object.values(properties)
      ),
    [users]
  );

  // Load user data on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers().then(setUsers);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div>Properties </div>
      <div>
        {allProperties.map((property) => (
          <div key={property.property_id}>
            <h1>{property.property_name}</h1>
            <p>{property.description}</p>
            <p>{property.rooms}</p>
            <p>{property.phone}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <p>oi</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

The memo hook will recompute `allProperties` any time `users` is changed.

---

If you don't need the `users` state, then there's not much need for the memo hook. Instead, just maintain the state you do need

```js
const [allProperties, setAllProperties] = useState([]); // init with empty array

useEffect(() => {
  getUsers().then((users) => {
    setAllProperties(
      Object.values(users).flatMap(({ properties }) =>
        Object.values(properties)
      )
    );
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was reading about memo hooks on an article on medium and they said to be wary of it and avoid using it if you can ...

Comment: @lams that's why I mentioned about using `users`. If you're not, you can just as simply set `allProperties` as your component state. I'll update my answer

Comment: your solution worked though, i only need the property information, not the user info

Comment: @lams see my last edit. In general, be wary of adding unnecessary complexity. Using memo hooks is fine if you need both pieces of data

Comment: noted, ill do some reading on that, thanks!